# Jenkins Artifactory plugin not resolving artifacts

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

Artifactory provides a Jenkins plugin and according to the docs it is supposed to

> resolve artifacts from Artifactory and deploy artifacts and build information to Artifactory.

I published a library to Artifactory and now I'm trying to build a project that consumes that library

#### My Setup

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Jenkins gradle build-step**

Runs `./gradlew assemble`

**Gradle-Artifactory Integration**:

Enabled, but since I only need/want artifacts to be resolved from Artifactory, I've configured my Artifactory server and resolution repository, but disabled everything else.

My build currently fails with the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.mygroup:mylib:latest.integration.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/mygroup/mylib/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/mygroup/mylib/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mygroup/mylib/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mygroup/mylib/
         file:/mnt/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/mygroup/mylib/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/mnt/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/mygroup/mylib/
         file:/mnt/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/mygroup/mylib/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/mnt/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/mygroup/mylib/
     Required by:
         My Job:app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Clearly, gradle is not searching Artifactory for the artifact.

#### Question

How can I get the Artifactory plugin for Jenkins to tell gradle to resolve artifacts from my Artifactory server? Even just getting gradle to *look* there would be a start.

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory is not jcenter. If your library only deployed to Artifactory, you need to set up your build to take the dependencies from Artifactory. You have too ways to achieve it: in Jenkins and in Gradle.

### Setting up Jenkins

You set up Jenkins to use Artifactory for your dependencies, using the [Artifactory Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin).

Install the plugin, setup Artifactory server in the settings and then in job configuration check the "Resolve artifacts from Artifactory" checkbox.

### Or, setting up Gradle

Another option might be instructing Gradle to use your Artifactory server as dependencies repository. Probably something like this will do the job:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://myartifactoryhost:80801/artifactory/libs-releases"
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to replace the host and the port and you might also want to change the name of the repository if you prefer to resolve the artifacts from another one (like `libs-snapshots`).

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Baruch. As I mentioned in my question (although I should have made it more clear) I'm already using the Jenkins plugin and have enabled Gradle-Artifactory integration in the job. There is no "resolve artifacts from artifactory" check box, but I've selected my artifactory server and my resolution repository. Am I missing something?

Comment: Same issue - no "resolve artifacts from artifactory" option for Gradle - it's only there for Maven.